# how to dynamically assign a variable to a console application c#

Tags: c#, string, web-services, variables, dynamic

I have a console application that it get executed automatically every day. Inside the code, there's a variable string that is hard coded with a projectId. The problem is that I need to execute the console 7 times with 7 different projectID. I cannot enter them as a array because this is web service and the method only accept string types.
Is there a way to call the console application, that execute the first time and then go to the second projectID variable and so on?

Here you have the code from my application.

```
string ProjectID = "5c14684f-32a5";

var dt1 = DateTime.Today;
var dt2 = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1);

string OutputType = "caption";
string currentLanguage = "en-US";
string DateFormatStr = "MM/dd/yy hh:mm:ss tt";
string DateFormatFrom = dt1.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); 
string FilloutDateTo = dt2.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); 
string subjetID = "";
string ConditionID = "";

//DateTime 
String path = @"C:\TEMP\test.zip";

String finalPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(path),
               Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path)
              + DateTime.Now.ToString("_yyyyMMdd HHmms")
              + Path.GetExtension(path));

byte[] MyBinFiles = db.ResponseFile(ProjectID, OutputType, currentLanguage, 
    DateFormatStr, DateFormatFrom, FilloutDateTo, subjetID, ConditionID);

System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(finalPath, MyBinFiles);
```

Comment: `foreach (string ProjectID in {"proj1", "proj2", "etc"})`?  Or do you want a new run of the process on the next ProjectID on each postback?

Comment: You could have the input be a comma-separated string of each project and then split the string into an array inside the web service and loop on the results.

Comment: Hi, the idea it that it run a new process after 3 minutes to make sure that the files is well downloaded

Comment: You proabaly looking for passing / handling command line arguments, but maybe not... Please clarify if command line arguments is what you are looking for OR why it does not work for your case.

Comment: Hi, I need a automatic execution no user manipulation, so if the command line arguments will work I can check. The thing is that the projectId is already entered into the code, so maybe a way to put a empty string and then with a command enter the 7 projectID?

Comment: It seems like what you're looking for is to pass command line arguments to your application. An easy way to do this would be using a batch file and running your executable through it.
Your application would use code like this:
Integer.TryParse(args(0), ProjectID) where args would be an argument to your main function for example

Comment: so what I could do its to have a batch file with the projectID inside so when the console is executed a first time the batch file enter the first projectId and so on?

Comment: Correct. You could have multiple command line arguments in your batch file and pass them to your executable, and populate your list of project ID's from there.

Comment: Sorry again but just to make sure. So I will have to have a console Console.Read() and Console.WriteLine() for the projectID variable so the batch file will enter it?

Comment: Are you expecting user input? If not, your batch file would look like this: "path to your executable" 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
--where 1 through 7 are your project ID's
and you would execute your .bat file instead of your .exe
In your console application, you would have an argument passed to your main function and would use that to populate a local projectID list. This way, anytime your Project ID's change, you would only update your .bat file.

Comment: No I am not expecting any user input. I going to try that I am not very familiar with batch files but I am going to look for it. Thanks

Comment: I made a batch file that execute the console.exe and put the 5 project id on it by separate them with spaces. But how the console know how to do the interaction between the console and the batch file? do I need to include something into de main()? thanks –

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it, because every time your application is closed, the memory is deallocated and you loose all your variable values.

You can:

- Pass ProjectID to your application as command line argument.  You can create the PowerShell script which run your program 5 times with different parameter (ProjectID).
- You can store ProjectIDs in the text file/  Every time the program will be launched it will read the text file to get the next ProjectID.

If you want to hide ProjectIDs you can:

- Crypt the text file with ProjectIDs and decrypt it in your console application.
- You can store in your exe-file all 5 ProjectIds and write to text file only the number of the next one - for example, 3th.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Can you please give me an aide to how to pass the ProjectID as command line argument? you said to create the PowerSehll script to run it 5 times. But i am lost a bit. thanks you

Comment: I made a batch file that execute the console.exe and put the 5 project id on it by separate them with spaces. But how the console know how to do the interaction between the console and the batch file? do I need to include something into de main()? thanks

Comment: Look at this examples http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288457(v=vs.71).aspx